# prove that $f(\bigcap^n_i X_i) \subset\bigcap^n_if(X_i) $

Tags: general-topology

If $f:A \to B$ and $\{X_i\}^n_i$ is a collection of subsets of $A$, how to prove that
 $$f\left(\bigcap^n_i X_i\right) \subset\bigcap^n_if(X_i) $$

I have a basic understanding of why it is true, but I don't understand how to write the proof formally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $b\in f\left(\bigcap X_i\right)$. By the definition of the image of a set under a function, there exists some $a\in A$ such that $a\in\bigcap X_i$ and $b=f(a)$. But then $a\in X_i$ for all $i$, so that $b=f(a)\in f(X_i)$. Since this is true for all $i$, it follows that $b\in \bigcap f(X_i)$.

Conclusion: any element of $ f\left(\bigcap X_i\right)$ is also an element of $\bigcap f(X_i)$, so that $ f\left(\bigcap X_i\right)\subseteq \bigcap f(X_i)$.

---

The inclusion can be strict. To see this, let $A=B=\mathbb R$, and $f(a)=a^2$ for all $a\in\mathbb R$. Let $X_1=(0,\infty)$ and $X_2=(-\infty,0)$. Then, $f(X_1)=f(X_2)=(0,\infty)$, so that $f(X_1)\cap f(X_2)=(0,\infty)$. On the other hand, $X_1\cap X_2=\varnothing$, so that $f(X_1\cap X_2)=\varnothing$. In this particular case, $f(X_1\cap X_2)$ is a proper subset of $f(X_1)\cap f(X_2)$.

---

However, the inclusion goes both ways if $f$ is injective. To see this, suppose that $f$ is injective and take any $b\in \bigcap f(X_i)$. Then, $b\in f(X_i)$ for each $i$, so that there exists for each $i$ some $a_i\in X_i$ such that $b=f(a_i)$. But $f$ is injective, so that actually all of the $a_i$’s must be one and the same—denote it as $a$. By the foregoing, $a\in X_i$ for all $i$, so that $a\in\bigcap X_i$. Therefore, $b=f(a)\in f\left(\bigcap X_i\right)$.

---

Note that the number of $X_i$’s involved in the intersections need not be finite. The proofs go through even if the index set over which intersections are taken contains infinitely (countably or uncountably) many elements.

Answer (score 5):

Let $y \in f(\bigcap X_i)$. This means that there is some $x \in \bigcap X_i$ such that $f(x)=y$. Since $x \in \bigcap X_i$, $x \in X_i$ for all $i$. So $y \in f(X_i)$ for all $X_i$, so $y \in \bigcap f(X_i)$. Therefore, $f(\bigcap X_i) \subset \bigcap f(X_i)$.

Comment: Okay, and if we want the statement above to be an equation (such that we can prove inclusion the other way as well), would we require the function $f$ to be bijective for it?

Comment: @user319373 Injectiveness is sufficient. I expanded my answer.